# Android Studio: Automatically start an activity with extras when run the project

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an application with many activities and most of these activities open with extras.
The problem is that when i build an inner activity every time i hit run in android studio i had to run the scenario manually to open the last activity i build. 
For example i have to pass home screen to hit menu to choose date and then i to see that activity.

I am wondering if there is any automatically way to make android studio to run all these scenarios for me when i hit run.

Changing the manifest would do the job but i want to start some inner activities with extras:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: can you explain your problem in more details ?

Comment: This is not a code question but  a question. So i have not any code to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two suggestions:

1- If you are looking for a short-term solution, introduce a `boolean test` variable and in your `onResume()` of `MainActivity` try to start the intent you want with your behavioral test data. Something like:

```
protected void onResume()
{
   if(test)
   {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra(data);
      startActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

2- A longer term solution is to use test libraries like `Espresso` (http://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html) to test your UI and use behavioral inputs to instruct the UI where to go next

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have heard about espesso and BDD libraries and i think i follow this road. But i  wonder if there is any better way to accomplish this. You first solution is not ideal in my case.

Comment: @p.leo the first solution is temporary but I strongly suggest the second one

Comment: Yes i understood it. I will wait to see if there are any other alternatives, if not i will accept your answer. Thanks for the help!